# Are "to it" and "about it" optional in these kind of sentences?

Tags: meaning

Examples:

> 1. His story has a ring of truth **about** / **to it**.
> 2. His voice had a familiar ring **about** / **to it**.
> 3. Their protestation of innocence had a hollow / false ring **about** / **to it**.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard "ring about it".

It is "ring to it".

This is an idiom, I don't think it's about option.

See [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+ring+to+it).

Comment: Well, I questioned this, because I found this sentence without "to it" in Longman "His explanation has the ring of truth." (http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ring_1)

Comment: It rings true - same idiom